# Open CV Camera Calibration Projector-like scenario

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, distortion

I have a conceptual understanding problem. Best is to tell you what i have and what i want to achieve: I have two pictures, one distorted, one undistorted (basically both simulated pictures only, can be chessboards, can be anything).

Basically it is not a camera, i am looking at, but a projector, and as i said, i have simulated images only.

My task is to calculate the distortion coefficients with OpenCV.

What i came up so far, failed miserably, basically (i think) because camera calibration works only well with a certain magnitude of images, which are of different planes, so the automatic tutorial-like approach doesn't work.

However, and here i am way out of my league and i am basically just guessing:

I think, i don't really need a Camera matrix, i am superhappy with the Unity Matrix there, i don't need to fiddle around with those coefficients, so i need tvecs, rvecs and the distortion coefficents.
I tried camera calibration a lot, the distorted image became a fake object (z=0 [is that correct or just stupid?]), and i get results, but very false results.

tvecs and rvecs alone are not a real problem, i can get those - if i want - with a perspective transform, which works well.

However is there any semiautomatic way how to get the distortion coefficients and only those out of two pictures, one distorted, one undistorted?
I tried Camera Calibration without real success

Edit: i wrote some code, maybe this highlights my problem. The manual distortion/undistortion works fine (most parameters zero for simplification), but he cam-calibration is just a horrible mess. Is there any other function i can use and haven't found yet?

```py
#%%

import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Barrel distortion effect, which corresponds to negative radial displacement
#Pincushion distortion effect, which corresponds to a positive radial displacement.

# The distortion coefficients
k1 = -3e-2  
k2 = -5e-4 
p1 = 0e-4  
p2 = 0e-2  
k3 = 0e-12
k4 = 0e-5
k5 = 0e-9
k6 = 0e-14
s1 = 0e-3
s2 = 0e-7
s3 = 0e-3
s4 = 0e-7
tx = 0e-1
ty = 0e-3


dist = np.array([k1, k2, p1, p2, k3, k4, k5, k6, s1, s2, s3, s4, tx, ty], dtype = "float32")


# Generate Grid of Object Points
grid_size, square_size = [20, 20], 0.2
object_points = np.zeros([grid_size[0] * grid_size[1], 3], dtype="float32")
mx, my = [(grid_size[0] - 1) * square_size / 2, (grid_size[1] - 1) * square_size / 2]
for i in range(grid_size[0]):
    for j in range(grid_size[1]):
        object_points[i * grid_size[0] + j] = [i * square_size - mx, j * square_size - my, 0]

# Plot the points 
plt.scatter(object_points[:, 0], object_points[:, 1])
plt.title("Original Object, Object Plane")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim((-4, 4))
plt.ylim((-4, 4))
plt.grid()
plt.show()

# Setup the camera information
fx=2.
fy=2.
cx= 0.
cy= 0.
alpha = 0   #### skew factor  accounts for a shear of the coordinate system
mtx = np.array([[fx, alpha, cx], [0, fy, cy], [0, 0, 1]])
rvec = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
tvec = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])


#### Distort the points, res is on the Image Plane
image_points, jacobian = cv2.projectPoints(object_points, rvec, tvec, mtx, dist)

# Plot the points 
plt.scatter(*zip(*image_points[:, 0, :]))
plt.title("distorted, Image Plane")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim((-4, 4))
plt.ylim((-4, 4))
plt.grid()
plt.show()



# undistort Points back with known cameramatrix and Dist-Coefficients, works well
undistpoints= cv2.undistortPoints(src= image_points , cameraMatrix= mtx, distCoeffs=dist)

# Plot the points 
plt.scatter(*zip(*undistpoints[:, 0, :]))
plt.title("after undistort, Object Plane ")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim((-4, 4))
plt.ylim((-4, 4))
plt.grid()
plt.show()

objp =[object_points]
imp= [undistpoints]
retval, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objectPoints=objp, imagePoints=imp, imageSize=(100,100), cameraMatrix= None, distCoeffs= None)

print("Cam Mat:")
print(cameraMatrix)
print("Dist Coeff:")
print(distCoeffs)
print(rvecs)
print(tvecs)
```

Comment: you DO need a camera matrix, because the whole distortion model is related to it. Can you share the points (distorted/undistorted) and maybe visualizations of your setting? What kind of model was used for the simulated distortion? If you have enough points I would set the principal point to the projection center and any fx/xy with fixed camera matrix. In addition you could try to limit the number of distortion coefficients.

Comment: for understanding: Are you using the projector as-is and a virtual camera without distortion at the same position as the projector? Or a virtual camera at a static position and the projector moving? You want to estimate distortion of the projector?

Comment: Thx for the fast answer: I don't have a camera. but an optical system, which produces distortion and I want to "undistort" the whole system. Blatantly simple the question is: can i send changed images through the system, so that i get more or less "better" more "undistorted" pictures on the image plane? I doesn't have to be "perfect" it is not a real projector.
What i understand is, i have the inverse problem of the camera calibration. i change object and image plane, however in my use-case  i don't have any camera intrinsics and i cant change or tilt images for my camera.

Comment: for your second question: "Are you using the projector as-is and a virtual camera without distortion at the same position as the projector?" i would say, that my simulated pictures correlates to this use case

Comment: ok, so you are basically changing the image in different distortions, but how do you check the result on the target surface? Also, this kind of "distortion optimization" will probably only work for a single "calibrated" surface. so rvec and tvec of your projector (relative to the target surface) don't make any sense if I understand it right.

Comment: If you project a distorted/not-distorted to a surface and capture the surface with another camera, make sure your camera-lens itself is already undistorted and only MEASURE the distortion of your projected image (e.g. the straightness of lines), it doesnt make sense to call a camera calibration there, because the distortion is in the pattern and not in the camera-lens but on the surface.

Comment: Hi Micka! Thx again for your input. There is a misunderstanding here. I work with simulated images ONLY. I rephrase my question: Is it possible to calculate an undistortion, when tvecs, rvecs is zero for a certain "fixed" intrinsic camera matrix, which i assume to be the identity. Since i have two images and not an object and an image, it is my understanding, that i can transfer one image back to be an "object" by simply using said identity. Then i want to calculate the distortion - still using the same identity. For the purpose of better understanding: I provide 2 simple images (fisheye

Comment: Identity doesnt make much sense as a camera matrix. You wont get any useful distortions from that. But anyways it should/could work.  Can you try to use calibrateCamera options that use the provided camera matrix and leave it unchanged? If I were you I would also start with only maybe 5 distortion coefficients and limit calibrateCamera to optimze those. Parameters CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS and CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT and CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO and CALIB_FIX_FOCAL_LENGTH and CALIB_FIX_ for some of the distortion coeffs.

Comment: See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d